# Exchange full NZ bike licence to UK and get tricycle

Tags: driving-license

My brother exchanged his NZ licence and received a UK licence that only allows him to ride a tricycle. I had an identical licence and exchanged mine for a full UK bike licence.
Apart from having to resit his tests and get a UK bike licence what else can he do?  To me this is a simple clerical error that DVLA should correct.

Comment: You don't offer enough information to research the issue. Are you or your brother residents of the UK? If so, for how long and on what status? At the time of the exchange(s), had either NZ license expired ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We both have parental ancestry and UK residency and been living here over 20 years.  Both his and my is NZ licences were current.

Comment: You should probably clarify whether you mean _motorcycles_ or _bicycles_ when you are talking about "bikes" and "tricycles." I assume you mean motorcycle, but I don't think I've ever heard of it referred to as a "bike licence."

Comment: I wouldn't normally answer this sort of reply but I think it could be inferred quite easily I'm talking about motorcycles when you consider you don't actually need a drivers licence to ride a bicycle.  If you feel compelled to post unhelpful comments like this I wouldn't bother ...

Answer (score 1):

This [UK govt page](https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence) discusses exchanging a drivers licence obtained overseas for a UK license. Because NZ is a "designated country," the page says the NZ license can be transferred.

Because a driver's license for a car will only exchange for a UK driver's license for car, and the same for motorcycles, I infer that an applicant's driving privileges can't be changed in the exchange. You've said both of you had the same type of NZ licenses, allowing unrestricted motorcycle use.

I assume you both filled out DVLA's form D-1; the form, unfortunately, is not available for download so I cannot see it. I'd expect it to require the applicant to specify the type of license for which exchange is sought.

If the D-1 form asked that information, and you both provided it, then I agree that DVLA erred because the results weren't the same. Because I don't know the actual underlying UK law...it's possible that DVLA erred as to *your license* and took the correct action with *his.*

I think the three courses of possible action are: 1) have your brother go to DVLA and raise the issue with them; 2) do nothing, with your brother starting the motorcycle licensing procedure anew if he wishes; or 3) consult with a solicitor who knows about UK driver's licenses.

I'm a retired attorney in the US, and always wanting to know the answer (i.e., in which case did DVLA err?) before I engage, favor alternative #3. With easier access to UK law, and knowing how to look it up, this shouldn't pose a significant challenge for a legal practitioner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes I had considered that they may well have erred in regard to my own which is why I haven't pursued it very rigorously with the DVLA.  He (my brother) is kicking off the process of getting his full licence now anyway so will leave it at that.